# OxyPlot - Cursors

Tags: c#, winforms, data-visualization, oxyplot

I'm trying to switch from National Instruments Measurement Studio ScatterGarph control to OxyPlot.

I'm able to do line plots with OxyPlot similar to the NI ScatterGraph.

I would like to add cursors to the OxyPlot similar to the NI ScatterGraph, see the attached screen shot:

[image: NI ScatterGrapg Cursors]

The cursor should snap to the nearest data point.

What I tried so far:

- The `Tracker` of OxyPlot is only shown when the mouse is pressed. And I think there is only one tracker possible.
- Using annotations: a `PointAnnotation` and two `LineAnnotation` for each cursor. I can make the annotations movable by using the `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` and `MouseUp` events of the annotations, but the cursor is not snapping to the nearest data point.

What would be the best way to add cursors to OxyPlot?

Comment: Did you manage to do that in the end? I'm looking to achieve something similar

Comment: No. I had as well other problems with OxyPlot, see https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/1651. Therefor I gave up.